# moment.js: Return the first and last day of each month within an interval

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, momentjs

I am trying to return an array that would give me the first and last day of each month, taking into account the start and end dates for the first and last month of the interval.

I can't seem to get get my head around it. I'm only able to do separate bits :'(

Any charitable soul out there to help me understand?

```js
var startDate = moment('2021-08-23');
var endDate = moment('2022-03-22');

var months = [];

if (endDate.isBefore(startDate)) {
    throw "End date must be greater than start date."
}      

while (startDate.isBefore(endDate)) {
    months.push(startDate.format("YYYY-MM-01"));
    startDate.add(1, 'month');
}

console.log(months);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Here, I'm getting

```
2021-08-01,
2021-09-01,
2021-10-01,
2021-11-01,
2021-12-01,
2022-01-01,
2022-02-01
```

When I'm really trying to get

```
[
[2021-08-23, 2021-08-31],
[2021-09-01, 2021-09-30],
[2021-10-01, 2021-10-31],
[2021-11-01, 2021-11-30],
[2021-12-01, 2021-12-31],
[2022-01-01, 2022-01-31],
[2022-02-01, 2022-02-29],
[2022-03-01, 2022-03-31]
]
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In to subarray that you push in main array you forgot to calculate the date for the month end.
It's better to use `start` and `end Of` in this case, without became crazy to calculate the correct number of day of month

```js
const startDate = moment('2021-08-23');
const endDate = moment('2022-03-22');

const months = [];

if (endDate.isBefore(startDate)) {
  throw Error('End date must be greater than start date.');
}

while (startDate.isBefore(endDate)) {
  months.push([
    startDate.startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    startDate.endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
  ]);
  startDate.add(1, 'month');
}

console.log(months);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

UPDATE:
I you want delimiter the start date and the end date using `startDate`and `endDate` you can add a controll in every cycle.

In this snip I use a [Ternary operator](Conditional (ternary) operator) for the check (I don't know if you saw that yet).

And a very important thing I done is the `.clone()` of moment for to do editing operarions like `.endOf()` and `.startOf()`.

```js
const startDate = moment('2021-08-23');
const endDate = moment('2022-03-22');

const months = [];

if (endDate.isBefore(startDate)) {
  throw Error('End date must be greater than start date.');
}

const cursor = startDate.clone();

while (cursor.isSameOrBefore(endDate, 'month')) {
  const firstDay = cursor.startOf('month').isBefore(startDate) ? startDate : cursor.clone().startOf('month');
  const lastDay = cursor.endOf('month').isAfter(endDate) ? endDate : cursor.clone().endOf('month');

  months.push([firstDay.format('YYYY-MM-DD'), lastDay.format('YYYY-MM-DD')]);

  cursor.add(1, 'month');
}

console.log(months);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for that!!! Now that I'm seeing it, it seems obvious but I just couldn't get to it. Thank you! I'm left with one question now: how do I take into account the actual start and end dates of the interval though? Like in my example, it starts on 23 MAR and ends on 22 FEB.

Comment: I edited the answer with an update on your second question.

Comment: thank you, this teaches me so much! I was fiddling around with splice, until you enlightened me!